# Building a Custom Scikit-Learn Imputer

Tags: python, class, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm working on building a custom Scikit-Learn transformer. Specifically, my goal is to impute feature columns that apply to a user specified threshold, the fraction of instances that are not a Nan type. For example, if the threshold were set to 90% and feature 1 was composed of 50% NaN types, while feature 2 was composed of 95% NaN types, then the algorithm would drop the first feature and impute the second one.

I've generated a working structure, but since I'm new to programming I would love some advice regarding the following issues: Do I need to define imputer = Imputer(...) in every method, or is there a more seamless way to do this? Currently, my code works if I call fit_transform on an instance, however, it fails if I call transform, how should I integrate fit and transform to fix this? Is there an easier way to grab Imputer's statistics_ attribute rather than create a method for it?

Note, the transform code doesn't actually do what I want perfectly yet, but I'm currently more concerned with the class structure and should be able to fix up the functionality myself.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

class CustomImputer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Custom imputation transformer for completing missing values provided
    they meet the user specified threshold.
    """
    def __init__(self, threshold, strat):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.strat = strat
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        """Fit the imputer on X.
        """
        imputer = Imputer(strategy=self.strat)
        return imputer.fit(X)
    def statistics_(self):
        """Documentation...
        """
        imputer = Imputer(strategy=self.strat)
        self.statistics_ = imputer.fit(X).statistics_
        return self.statistics_
    def transform(self, X):
        """Impute all missing values in X that meet the user specified threshold.
        """
        imputer = Imputer(strategy=self.strat)
        nulls = X.isnull().sum()
        size = X.shape[0]
        for i in range(X.shape[1]):
            if (1 - nulls[i] / size) < self.threshold:
                X.drop(X.columns[i], axis=1) # drop features that don't meet criteria? other options?
        return imputer.transform(X)


df = pd.read_csv("fact_sage_data.csv")
X = df.drop(["cmpd", "H_eVatom"], axis=1)
plz_impute = CustomImputer(0.99, "median")
X_imputed = plz_impute.fit_transform(X) # in this specific case it dropped 75 features
```

Comment: You define it in init(), instantiate it in fit() and use in transform().